# How navigation bar behaves during popViewControllerAnimated?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have a problem durning animation of    `popViewControllerAnimated`

There are 2 view controllers, first one has navigation controller already pushed.
I'm pushing 1 controller to 2nd controller and I'm creating custom backButtonItem with custom method which includes `popViewControllerAnimated`. And then 3 strange dots appear as in the image below:

[image]

What could have happen so those 3 dots appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you use:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

somewhere in your view controllers.

If you create custom back button you shouldn't touch this property. Otherwise three dots appear while you animate between view controllers.

If it won't help you, please provide source code of how you create your custom button.